# How to encourage haze?

Tags: clarity, cloudy

I've got a beer that, for aesthetic reasons, I'd like to make *more* hazy. I've used torrified wheat in the mash, and tried adding flour to the boil. Those do make the beer hazy at first, but it tends to settle after a week or two in keg. Is there any way to obtain a more stable haziness? I've seen pectin mentioned as a source of hard-to-get-rid-of haze, but there's no fruit in the recipe, and I'm not sure how much powdered pectin I'd have to add to get haze without getting globs of jelly as well.

In case it matters, I do all-grain brewing, and keg with forced carbonation.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends upon how much haze you are looking for. While most brewers spend their energies trying to remove haze, you could simply leave out all those steps that go towards reducing haze:

- use water with low hardness (has low colloidal stability)
- avoid protein rests in the mash to maintain as much protein as possible
- use a significant portion of malted or flaked wheat
- leave out calcium in the mash - calcium helps reduce hazes
- leave out finings in the boil (whirlfloc/irish moss)
- chill slowly (avoiding the cold break)
- copper at >1mg/l (1ppm) causes irreversible haze
- serve chilled to promote a chill haze

See [Beer Haze](http://www.brewrats.org/go/default/brewing-info/beer-haze/) for more details on hazes, and colloidal stability.

Applying some of these omissions may have side-effects, since most of these steps are typically beneficial for the beer, not just because they reduce haziness.

Answer (score 2):

Low flocculating yeast (like weiss/witbier) should get you the required look. The rest that you mention should work. I have not tried to make a hazy beer, so I can't offer any more assistance.

Comment: Sure, but that leads to a distinctly yeasty flavor. I'd like to add haze without affecting the taste.